# How can I get merkle proof in Ethereum?

Tags: web3j, merkle-patricia-tries

I am trying to figure out the check of existence and the immutability of the transaction in the Ethereum block, but I do not know how to get the Merkle branch. With the help of web3j, I can get the block number by the hash of the transaction, and then get the full list of transactions by the block number. But there must be a way to get only those transactions that are needed for verification - Merkle proof. How can I get only needed hashes? I will be glad to any help!

Answer (score 1):

The Patricia trie used in Ethereum is different from a Merkle tree, so the Merkle proof is different as well.

In a Patricia trie Merkle proof, you need to know the key being accessed and a full list of nodes accessed to get to the value.