# Examples of light-client interactions to extract Merkle proofs?

Tags: blocks, merkle-patricia-tries

I'd be grateful for pointers to working examples of interacting with the [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)/[parity](https://wiki.parity.io/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-(LES).html) light-client protocols. I'm particularly interested in working code which shows how to extract the Merkle proof that a transaction (or transaction receipt) is included in a block hash.

**NB**: This question is sort of similar to [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/ethereum-how-to-get-merkle-proof), but it has a little more texture, and I'm hoping the documentation has improved since then.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in the case of `geth`, I would want to start [in the LES handler test](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/les/handler_test.go#L315), in which case I've reduced the question to how to send such a request to a node following main net.

**ETA**: <del>[This javascript client looks very promising](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-devp2p/blob/master/src/les/index.js).</del> Currently, that client does not implement the relevant LES requests.